# Parse Linux command output

Tags: linux, parsing, awk, grep

For command,
`amixer get PCM playback`

I got output like this:

```
 "Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 255 [100%] [0.00dB]"
```

Now I need value "100%" in a variable; so, how can I parse it?

I am getting `[100` with this:

```
amixer get PCM playback | grep "\[" | cut -d '%' -f1 | awk '{print $5}'
```

Comment: First off, there are two `100%` numbers; which did you want? If they're always `100%`, then you can simply assign `var=100`, so presumably they can sometimes be less than 100%.  It looks a bit like a case for `sed`, such as: `amixer get PCM playback | sed -n '/.*\[\([0-9]*\)%].*/s//\1/p'`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : It can be any value between 0 to 100, and i want any of 100, its place in output is fixed.

Comment: OK; so the `sed` command I showed should give you two numbers on two lines of output, with front left preceding front right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: How to collect it in a variable?

Comment: `x=$(amixer | sed)` in outline.  The [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) is the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there are two `100%` numbers in the sample output; which did you want? If they're always `100%`, then you can simply assign `var=100`, so presumably they can sometimes be less than `100%`.

It looks a bit like a case for `sed`, such as:

```
amixer get PCM playback | sed -n '/.*\[\([0-9]*\)%].*/s//\1/p'
```

The `sed` command should give you two numbers on two lines of output, with front left value preceding front right.

You collect the output from `sed` in a variable using [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution):

```
playback=$(amixer get PCM playback | sed -n '/.*\[\([0-9]*\)%].*/s//\1/p')
```

This will give the two numbers in `playback`.  You might prefer to use an array instead:

```
playback=( $(amixer get PCM playback | sed -n '/.*\[\([0-9]*\)%].*/s//\1/p') )
```

Now you can use:

```
left=0
right=1
echo "Left = ${playback[$left]}"
echo "Right = ${playback[$right]}"
```

This assumes you are using `bash` as your shell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.
Store left value in variable `left`

```
left=$(amixer get PCM playback | awk -F"[%[]" '/Left:/ {print $2}')
```

Store right value in variable `right`

```
right=$(amixer get PCM playback | awk -F"[%[]" '/Right:/ {print $2}')
```

Or store both data in in variable `db`

```
db=$(amixer get PCM playback | awk  -F"[%[]" '/dB/ {print $2}')
echo "$db"
100
100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Gnu grep and Perl regex with positive lookahead and lookbehind, you can get the left-speaker value as

```
grep -Po '(?<=Left: Playback 255 \[)[^]]*(?=%\])'
```